# Syntax highlighting with AvalonEdit

Tags: c#, regex, syntax-highlighting, avalonedit

I am trying to write a regex for `AvalonEdit.TextEditor` to mark everything after the second `|` a certain color.

Example(value should be a color):

> action|key|**value**

I am trying something like this but it doesn't work because I can't specify the group I wanna color.

```
^[^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|(?P<value>[^\|]*)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the `P` for? Without it it looks fine to me.

Comment: Try the following: `^[^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|\K[^\|]+` if - by any chance - the regex engine is not really .NET one, but is Onigmo/PCRE/Boost. It will work at regex101 with PHP option, but do not test there, test in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `(?<=[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|)(?<value>[^\|]+)`

The positive look-behind (`?<=`) will make sure `action` and `key` are not part of the match.

Normally you shouldn't use non-fixed length look-behinds but maybe this works for you.

Comment: This rule gives me a exception: 
A highlighting rule matched 0 characters, which would cause an endless loop. Change the highlighting definition so that the rule matches at least one character.

Also tried it here https://regex101.com/ with a different error: A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

Comment: regex101 doesn't have C# RegEx. Try [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester). Too bad this doesn't work with Avalon's textEditor. Can you provide a [mcve]? I replaced the `*` with `+` maybe that already does the trick.